# How to access parent variables in child window - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a simple search query. It takes user input from page 1. And I want to display results in page 2. Here's my code for page 1

```
                    var t1;
                    var t2;
                    var t3;
                    var t4;$("#submitsearch").on( 'click', function () {
                    t1 = $("#search0").val();
                    t2 = $("#search1").val();
                    t3 = $("#search2").val();
                    t4 = $("#search3").val();

                    window.open('testpage2.html','newWindow');
                    return false;
                });
```

Page 2 uses the variables t1,t2,t3 and t4.I access them like this.

```
                    var t;
                    var t1 = window.opener.t1;
                    var t2 = window.opener.t2;
                    var t3 = window.opener.t3;
                    var t4 = window.opener.t4;
```

But when I replace the 'newWindow' with '_self' I cannot access the variables anymore. 
I understand why, because the parent page is closing and thus cannot pass variables. But I was hoping for a workaround. Is there any?

I want to open page2 in the same window as where page1 was. Are there any other ways to do this while retaining these variables.

Comment: Why not put them into the URL? testpage2.html?myVar=1&myVar2=2
And using document.location, you can get them back.

Comment: u could use localstorage or one div for every page and show and hide them. Just 2 ways out of many...